# Ошибка при создании .apk с помощью buildozer в Windows/WSL(ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64)

Tags: python, pygame, компиляция, buildozer

в buildozer.spec изменил только requirements = python3,pygame,random
используемые модули в проекте: pygame,random

```
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Building jpeg for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg
[DEBUG]:   -> running rm -f CMakeCache.txt CMakeFiles/
[DEBUG]:   -> running cmake -G Unix Makefiles -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=1 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./install -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON -DENABLE_NEON=ON -DENABLE_SHARED=0 -DENABLE_STATIC=1
[DEBUG]:        CMake Warning:
[DEBUG]:          No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
[DEBUG]:          same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
[DEBUG]:          become a fatal error in future CMake releases.
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:        -- ANDROID_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version
[DEBUG]:        19.
[DEBUG]:        -- The C compiler identification is unknown
[DEBUG]:        -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[DEBUG]:        -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
[DEBUG]:        -- Check for working C compiler: /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
[DEBUG]:        -- Check for working C compiler: /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang - broken
[DEBUG]:        CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
[DEBUG]:          The C compiler
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:            "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang"
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:          is not able to compile a simple test program.
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:          It fails with the following output:
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:            Change Dir: /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:            Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_3fbcd/fast && make -j6  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/build
[DEBUG]:            make[1]: Entering directory '/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
[DEBUG]:            Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
[DEBUG]:            /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang   -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
[DEBUG]:            /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang: 5: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
[DEBUG]:            make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 2
[DEBUG]:            make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
[DEBUG]:            gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_3fbcd/fast] Error 2
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:          CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
[DEBUG]:        Call Stack (most recent call first):
[DEBUG]:          CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:        -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[DEBUG]:        See also "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[DEBUG]:        See also "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Exception in thread background thread for pid 15942:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/qw/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/qw/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/qw/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/qw/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /usr/bin/cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=1 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./install -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON -DENABLE_NEON=ON -DENABLE_SHARED=0 -DENABLE_STATIC=1

  STDOUT:
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


-- ANDROID_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version
19.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang - broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_3fbcd/fast && make -j6  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang   -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang: 5: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_3fbcd/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1312, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 734, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 212, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 504, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/jpeg/__init__.py", line 31, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.cmake, '-G', 'Unix Makefiles',
  File "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/qw/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/qw/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/qw/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /usr/bin/cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=1 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./install -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON -DENABLE_NEON=ON -DENABLE_SHARED=0 -DENABLE_STATIC=1

  STDOUT:
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


-- ANDROID_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version
19.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang - broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_3fbcd/fast && make -j6  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang   -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    /home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang: 5: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_3fbcd.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_3fbcd/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".


  STDERR:

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,pygame,random', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu-22.04'
#     NAME = 'DESKTOP-ASRSKA6'
#     PWD = '/home/qw'
#     LOGNAME = 'qw'
#     HOME = '/home/qw'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'qw'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     WSLENV = ''
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = ('/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common '
 'Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL '
 'Server/150/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client '
 'SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Users/yalf1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/yalf1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/:/mnt/c/Users/yalf1/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/d/games/PyCharm '
 '2022.2/bin:/mnt/c/Users/yalf1/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin:/home/qw/.local/bin/')
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     _ = '/home/qw/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/qw/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/qw/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: пипец, я не понял.Но знаю то что buildozer невозможно компилировать через Windows.Нужен только Linux